# Python DDL Error SQLite2

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, ddl

I am trying to create two tables. One called PRODUCT and the other called SUPPLIER. I am not getting any errors but whenever I open my database(SQLITE) there is only the SUPPLIER table but the PRODUCT table is missing. Please help, this is my code so far...

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('work2423')
print("Database has been opened successfully")

DDL = '''CREATE TABLE PRODUCT 
        (ProductCode VARCHAR(15),
         ProductName VARCHAR(35),
         SupplierID VARCHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
         CostPrice VARCHAR(6),
         SellPrice VARCHAR(6),
         QuantityStock INTEGER,
         ReorderLevel INTEGER)'''


DDL = '''CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER 
        (SupplierID VARCHAR(4) REFERENCES PRODUCT(SupplierID),
         SupplierName VARCHAR(25),
         TelNo VARCHAR(12),
         Email VARCHAR(25))'''

conn.execute(DDL)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are overwriting DDL variable, you want to probably concatenate it both (with ';' separator).

Comment: It is interesting that it can create a table that is referencing non existent table and column...just btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assigned DDL twice. The first one '''CREATE TABLE PRODUCT... was overwritten by the second one '''CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER... I would suggest calling conn.execute(DDL) immediately after the first DDL assignment. Keep the second call to conn.execute where it is since both SQL statements need to be executed.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it worked. I appreciate the help very much.